# Android: displaying a preview of widget in my own app

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm creating an App that has a homescreen widget, and I'd like to have it so the user can see a live preview of what the widget will look like, within my actual App activity, when they're configuring settings for the widget. I recently downloaded an app that did that exact thing, and it seemed like a great feature.

Any idea how I'd go about accomplishing this? I found some references to `AppWidgetHostView`, is that what I need?

I'm very new to Android development (as in just started the tutorials today), so bear with me if this question is missing anything important!

Answer (score 0):

> I found some references to AppWidgetHostView, is that what I need?

`AppWidgetHostView` is one option. I think you can put that in your layout and call `updateAppWidget()` on it, supplying your `RemoteViews`.

Or, your activity/fragment can [call `apply()` on the `RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#apply(android.content.Context,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) to have that UI poured into some `ViewGroup` (e.g., a `FrameLayout`).

In either case, you would need your function that creates your `RemoteViews` to be available to both your `AppWidgetProvider` and your activity/fragment that implements your preview.