# Android: Why is the button color in my widget different thhan in main activity?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I'm just learning Android development, trying to wrap my head around styling (with Material styles).

In my main app, I have a button that's a nice purple color. I didn't assign it any styles, I just dragged it onto the view. The background of my app is dark (because of my system settings). The material styles are listed as a dependency in the App-- when I create a normal button, do I need to assign it styles manually, or does it automatically become a material button?

I'm further confused by this because I created a homescreen widget (currently just a button in a relative view with no background on the view). It isn't purple, unlike the other button. It's just grey.

tl;dr; What accounts for the difference in the button colors between my main activity and homescreen app? The XML for both of the buttons is identical.

Comment: In the `Activity`, the `<Button>` in your layout XML is being automagically substituted with a `MaterialButton`, which has that purple style by default. That's happening because your `Activity` is an `AppCompatActivity` with a specialized `LayoutInflater` helper that swaps in AppCompat and Material versions of certain types of `View`s. No such substitutions are made in the App Widget. For comparison, you can disable the substitution in the `Activity` by specifying the fully qualified class name in the XML tag; e.g., `<android.widget.Button>`.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! Is there some way I can get that to apply to App Widgets as well? I tried manually setting `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Button` and it does *something*.. it makes the button extremely tiny on the homescreen, and it changes its text color, but not fill color and doesn't capitalize it. How can I apply material styles on the widget?

Comment: I just tried setting the button in the widget XML to manually use `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`, and it shows me "problem loading widget". I read something in passing about widgets being RemoteViews that have restrictions on the kind of views they can contain, with a finite list of views that apparently can't be extended. I'd assume material is extending buttons, and that's what the issue is?

Comment: You can only use certain platform classes in [`RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews). You can't use any kind of custom or library `View`, not even the official Google library ones. That also means that you can't just slap a `Theme.MaterialComponents` on a regular `Button`, because `Button` doesn't know anything about the custom library attributes that are styling `MaterialButton`. I'd never really thought about it before, but if you want that purple style in the App Widget, you might have to handle that manually.

Comment: [Here's the default style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/styles.xml#L25) for `MaterialButton`. All of the attributes with the `android:` prefix can be copied directly. However, several of the ones without that prefix – e.g., `shapeAppearance` – would need to be accounted for in some other way, because the platform `Button` class doesn't know what that is. Follow me?

Comment: That's disappointing, but understandable, thank you for the explanation. I just went through the android tutorial today, so very new to all this. I have another question about widgets if you happen to have a minute, since you seem knowledgeable about this stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73173232/android-displaying-a-preview-of-widget-in-my-own-app

Comment: and yeah, I follow you. I'll check out the default style, thanks!

Comment: @MikeM. one more related question: is there some way I can figure out the computed/actual attributes/styles on a Material button? I'm trying to style it myself, and got the color right, but it's hard to figure out e.g., the font family/attributes that are being used.

Comment: Well, in Android Studio, hovering your mouse over the `@style` _might_ show a popup that lists all the the attributes and values therein for the theme currently selected in the designer. I don't really recall how it behaves, exactly, or if there's some other way to bring that up. Beyond that, it's usually just digging through library resources; e.g., all of the `dimen`s in that style are in [this file](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/dimens.xml), the colors in another, etc.